# How to automatically call Pop-Location at end of scope

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a simple scope that is book-ended with Push-Location and Pop-Location:

```
Function MyFunction($Location)
{
  Push-Location $Location
  # do other stuff here
  Pop-Location
}
```

Is there any way to set it up at the beginning of the scope so that I don't have to remember to put the Pop-Location at the end?  Something like this:

```
Function MyFunction($Location)
{
  Setup-BothPushAndPopHere $Location
  # do other stuff here
  # at the end of the scope, Pop-Location is automatically called
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No.

My take on `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` is that you should generally avoid them, and adapt your script to use the path names in commands instead; in other words, instead of:

```
Push-Location $Location
Get-ChildItem
Pop-Location
```

Just do:

```
Get-ChildItem $Location
```

(simplified example)

If you must use the pattern, consider `try`/`finally`:

```
Push-Location $Location
try {
    # ...
} finally {
    Pop-Location
}
```

As this helps with unexpected exceptions or the user interrupting program execution.

I typically use the `try`/`finally` pattern when the code is outside my control; most often when loading the `SQLPS` module since it changes the current location to the SQL server provider which in my experience causes everything that uses the current location to become much slower.

As [Eris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100227/eris) points out, it's also useful when dealing with native applications. This can be especially true if it's painful to escape quotes around path names with spaces, or the application wouldn't handle it correctly anyway.

Comment: I think personally I would use a BEGIN{} PROCESS{} END{} structure. That is just a stylistic choice on my part though.

Comment: I use the `try/finally` version quite a lot. It's much cleaner than adding the folder argument to *every* command that I want to run in that folder.

Comment: @EBGreen that's more than a stylistic choice; it could dramatically change the execution. It may be necessary to push and pop on each pipeline item, which would require it to all be in the `process` block. And in that instance, `try`/`finally` might still be valid. It's difficult to account for exceptions or pipeline interruption with this pattern if `begin` and `end` make sense for `push` and `pop`. It's not a striaghtforward decision, imo.

Comment: @Eris you could use [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx) for that :)

Comment: @briantist Only if all the commands are native to powershell. I'm quite sure git doesn't use `$PSDefaultParameterValues`

Comment: @Eris good point; native applications can be be a good use case for push/pop, especially when they don't deal with paths with spaces well. I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: It's safer to put `Push-Location` in the `try` block since it still pushes the current directory onto the stack even if it fails.

Comment: @Jiro that's interesting, do you have any code that could demonstrate that? I suppose this whole method is somewhat ambiguous if `Push-Location` could fail both before and after adding a directory to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you try to do in the `#do other stuff here` code, you could try executing those commands as a script block in a child process. A skeleton-code example:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
  Push-Location $Location
  #commands
}

$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock   # Add other arguments if needed

# Check the status of the task:
Get-Job $Job

# Wait for the job state to be 'Completed' (do-while, maybe?)

# If your ScriptBlock writes any output, collect in a variable:
$Output = Receive-Job $Job

# Clean up:
Remove-Job $Job
```

The point of this approach is that you spawn a job to do the work (in the background) and you needn't worry about `Pop-Location` as you just let that child scope exit while you carry on doing whatever you need to do in your main script.

There are other posts here on StackExchange that go into more detail about [powershell-jobs](/questions/tagged/powershell-jobs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cool way to do it with script blocks

```
function withPath($action,$path) {
    Push-Location $path
    try 
    {
        & $action
    }
    finally
    {
        Pop-Location
    }
}
withPath { 
    Get-Location | Write-Host 
    withPath {
        Get-Location | Write-Host 
        throw "oh no, an inner exception!"
    } 'Program Files' #relative path
} 'C:\'
```