# How to prevent Set-Location in powershell script from changing the path of calling shell

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a simple powershell script:

```
# File: myscript.ps1
set-location C:\Windows
```

Then I invoke this script from the prompt as follows:

```
PS> Get-Location
C:\User\Dude

PS> .\myscript.ps1

PS> Get-Location
C:\Windows   #!!!!!!!!!
```

I don't want my script to change the calling shells path... how to prevent this?  Can I put something in the code to turn off exporting the PATH to the parent? or is there a way to somehow set it back to the original value before exiting the script, either on error or normal termination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically call Pop-Location at end of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923637/how-to-automatically-call-pop-location-at-end-of-scope)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than

```
Set-Location C:\Windows
```

Try using the Push-Location and Pop-Location in your script

```
 #start of script 
    Push-Location C:\Windows
    ...
    Pop-Location
 #end of script
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-7.2

[When to use Push-Location versus Set-Location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734408/when-to-use-push-location-versus-set-location/32734498)

Answer (score 2):

```
# Run ScriptBlock from a Temporary Path
function better_with_path {
    param(
        [string]$newpath,
        [ScriptBlock]$action
    )
    
    Push-Location $newpath
    try 
    {
        & $action
    }
    finally
    {
        Pop-Location
    }
}
```